# FB Like button on website generates a link on my FB page titled "Home". How do I change the name of this generated link?

Tags: tags, facebook-like

Just added the FB Like button to my website hosted on Host Gator.  When I click the Like button, it shows up on my FB page with the link "Home", which is very non-descriptive.  How do I change the Like button in the website, so it generates a link on FB that contains the name of my website, versus "Home".  Note: the pages in my website all contain the domain name in the page name, i.e, there is no page named "Home".

Comment: Did you follow **all** the instructions from here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/?  Notice that there is a "step 2"...